# comparing 2 list of dicts that works but sometimes not

Tags: python, dictionary

There are two lists of dict

```
ad_sets_list = [{'ad_id' : 120398, 'cpc' : 100},{'ad_id' : 120397, 'cpc' : 100}]
stats_load = [{'id' : 120398, 'pv' : 398},{'id' : 120399 : 'pv' : 3124}]

for i in ad_sets_list:
    for q in stats_load:
        if i['ad_id'] == q['id']:
            found = True
            break
        else:
            found = False
    if found == True:
        print(i['ad_id'])
```

I simplified the code that I wrote.
The problem with this is it works fine sometimes but it gives the following error on certain occasions

```
  File "c:\Python Projects\ad_automation\test.py", line 96, in db_save
    if found == True:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'found' referenced before assignment
```

As I think, at the nested for loop, there is no way not to assign `found` but it says `found` is referenced before assignment.
in what case the `found` cannot be assigned?
or is there any better method that I can take to compare two lists of **dicts**?

Comment: You either missed a `'` or there's one too much.

Comment: Are you trying to compare dicts for equality? What is your expected outcome and why?

Comment: set `found = False` before the loop, not as an `else`.

Comment: the original code checks if there is stuff with same id, then collects 'cpc' and other many stuffs and put them into another dataframe. if not, I put value of 0 to each keys

Comment: but I'm curious why it works sometimes....ofcourse there are found = true cases and found=false cases all the time. it won't be a missed a ' stuff...

Answer (score 3):

As written, if `stats_load` is empty, then `found` will not be defined/set when you reach `if found == True`.  Consider instead:

```
ad_sets_list = [{'ad_id': 120398, 'cpc': 100}, {'ad_id': 120397, 'cpc': 100}]
stats_load = [{'id': 120398, 'pv': 398}, {'id': 120399, 'pv': 3124}]

for dictionary_ad_sets in ad_sets_list:
    found = False

    for dictionary_stats in stats_load:
        if dictionary_ad_sets['ad_id'] == dictionary_stats['id']:
            found = True
            break

    if found:
            print(dictionary_ad_sets['ad_id'])
```

Comment: I'll defo try this. inspires a lot. Thank you!